# Using type defined in derived class from base class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a pure virtual template base class, in which I define a method get_value which takes an enumeration and returns an int. The complication is that each derived class will use a different enumeration. This isn't a problem if I just define the enumerations beforehand and pass them as template parameters to the base, however, since the enum type is directly related to the derived type, I want the enum to be defined within the derived class.

I was hoping to solve this by having the base class take the derived class as a parameter and then access the derived class's enum, like this:

```
template <typename child_type>
class base_type{
public:
    int get_value(typename child_type::enum_type);
};

class child : public base_type<child>{
public:
    enum enum_type{a,b,c};
};
```

MinGW reports

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'class base_type<child>':
test.cpp:7:22:   required from here
test.cpp:4:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class child'
  int get_value(typename child_type::enum_type index);
      ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:7:7: note: forward declaration of 'class child'
 class child : public base_type<child>{
       ^~~~~
```

I understand the errors; I just feel like there should be a way to do what I want to do and can't wrap my head around how to do it without getting too complicated. Is this possible, or am I going about it in the wrong way?

As for the specifics of my problem: the classes parse a record file which can be encoded in one of a few different encoding versions - the processing is mostly the same between versions and the bulk can be done in a non-virtual base function, with a call to a virtual function to do version-specific things. Different versions also extract slightly different value names, which I am trying to capture in the version-specific enums. The position of each named value inside the record will be stored in the value of the corresponding enum member value.

There's probably a better way to go about it but I haven't been able to think of it. I suppose in this case I could just have get_value take an int in the base class, use the child class enums to make the call, and just let the cast happen, but I was hoping to see if the more general case of a base class using a type defined in a child was possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The class definition of `child` is not complete until its closing brace. But in order to define the `child` class, it's necessary to fully define its superclass, of course. But the superclass ends up using a reference to `child` in a context where `child` must be defined completely. Circular dependency. Unfortunately, there is no magic button one can push in order to make a circular dependency go away. I see no options besides declaring enum in global scope (not a class member), and pass it as an additional template parameter.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called CRTP: the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

Comment: My gut tells me that there must be some problem in the domain analysis here. I cannot think of an example where such a construction would be a good design. If the base class knows of the existence of this enum, why is;t this defined in the base class itself? Can you give an example why this is necessary?

Comment: My slow brain now produced an answer to that. There must be another, virtual, function that needs this enum too, right? So the base class just needs to transport the enum value as a capsule. Easy to solve type-unsafe, but I see the point now.

Comment: @BertBril I added something to the question explaining what I was trying to do - I probably over-minimalized when trying to make an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of is using child traits.

```
template <typename child_type>
class base_type{
public:
    int get_value(typename child_type::enum_type);
};

struct child_traits {
enum enum_type{a,b,c};
};
class child : 
public child_traits, 
public base_type<child_traits>{

};
```